# Restrict network access from Apptainer/Singularity container

Tags: singularity-container, apptainer

Is it possible with Apptainer/Singularity to restrict which network interfaces can be used from within a container?

In my specific use-case I want to allow access to the internet but block access to some SocketCAN interfaces that are available on the host system.  Is this possible?

I saw the `--net`/`--network` options but the documentation on this option not very detailed so I'm not sure how to use it (or if it can solve my problem at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from the Apptainer Slack channel (thanks to Cedric Clerget!):

In my specific case (allowing normal network access but hiding the SocketCAN interfaces), it is actually enough to add

```bash
--dns <IP of DNS server> --net --network=bridge  # or --network=ptp
```

Specifying the DNS server is needed when using systemd resolved.  In other cases it may work without.